# Accidentally deleted code in header.php

Tags: templates

I accidentally deleted some code in my `<head>` section which made website header disappear. Later when add `<script type="text/javascript">` header is appearing now but, when i try to open my homepage, another page is opening. It's happening for all the pages. I can understand that I am missing a template which makes my header work, but I can't able to find out that code. It will be great If any one can guide me.

Comment: Hey hey, what exactly keeps you from redownloading the theme or a git reset?

Comment: Actually I am unable to contact my developer that's why I came here if anyone can guide me any other option

Comment: Hi Sidhartha, welcome to WPSE. Please note that WPSE is a Q&A site that is targeted for WordPress development related questions & answers. This is a support type question which is very specific to your site alone. Hence, it's not a suitable question for WPSE. If you can't contact the existing developer, then perhaps it's best to contact your webmaster or another developer who will be able to examine the files and provide you a more personalized solution. Hope to see you soon in WPSE with questions that are [on topic for this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).